# How to use this.template if app.js is not in document ready?

Tags: templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

I tried to follow http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/#inline_templates to avoid http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/#abuse however I have a typical view like this:

```
// in app.js
App.MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: "ui-widget-content",
    template: _.template($("#myTemplate").html()),
    render: function() 
    {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    }
```

Then I just include app.js like this

```
<script src="./js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="./js/backbone.js"></script>
<script src="./js/app.js"></script>
```

Browser complains that the `$("#myTemplate")` line in App.MyView.template is `null` (because document is not ready?).  What shall I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my quick fix for this was to compile the template on view initialisation..

```
App.MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: "ui-widget-content",
    template: '#myTemplate',
    initialize: function(){
        this.template = _.template($(this.template).html());
    },
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    }
```

then everything else still works the same and you can put your render method in a base class..

Answer (score 2):

Why not lazy-load your templates? Compile the template on first use and cache the compiled template in the view's "class". You could even add your base view to handle this caching with something like this:

```
var BV = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: function(data) {
        if(!this.constructor.prototype._template)
            this.constructor.prototype._template = _.template($('#' + this.tmpl_id).html());
        return this._template(data);
    }
});
```

Then you could have things like this:

```
var V = BV.extend({
    tmpl_id: 'tmpl',
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

and the `#tmpl` template would be compiled the first time it was used and it would be compiled at most once.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/hrnqC/

Notice the *no wrap (head)* in the demo and have a look at the console to see what is being compiled and how often.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is simply not cache the template:

```
App.MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: "ui-widget-content",
    render: function() 
    {
        var template = _.template($("#myTemplate").html())
        this.$el.html(template(this.model.toJSON()));
    }
```

Comment: yes, that'd be the easiest, but I thought the underscore 'compiling' is expensive and should be cached?

Comment: What's the context of the view? Is it rendered hundreds of times per page, or once?

Comment: If its a relatively small view, and not rendered more then a handful of time's I'd probably just drop the cache. As the main point.... I guess I don't really know. Maybe create everything but the View's early, and create the views after the ready event? I'm not 100% sure why this would even be considered an anti pattern. Very interesting links though, I'm reading it now.

Comment: Even this way, it's actually pretty easy to build a template cache.  Instead of always compiling on render, have an intermediary object which either compiles the template or fetches the compiled one.

Comment: I'd pretty new at backbone :)